# Нужно ли здесь ставить запятую?

Tags: пунктуация

Юнги знает, что ровно через тридцать три минуты сорок секунд послышится громкое шарканье по подъездной лестнице (?) и в дверной звонок позвонят.

Answer (score 4):

Юнги знает, что ровно через тридцать три минуты сорок секунд послышится громкое шарканье по подъездной лестнице и в дверной звонок позвонят.

Это СПП с однородными изъяснительными придаточными, запятая не ставится.

Answer (score 4):

> Юнги знает, что ровно через тридцать три минуты сорок секунд послышится громкое шарканье по подъездной лестнице и в дверной звонок позвонят.

"Юнги знает" - главное предложение, к которому "привязано" два однородных придаточных, поэтому запятая не нужна.

Цитата из справочника орфографии Лопатина ([параграф 119](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=375))

> Между двумя придаточными, соединенными одиночными соединительными или разделительными союзами **и, или, либо, да** (в значении «**и**»), запятая не ставится (при этом подчинительный союз или союзное слово может и не повторяться):
>
> "Подходя к дому, я вспомнил, что неподалеку в еловом перелеске с можжевельником не раз спугивал старого петуха-черныша **и** еще там жила матка с одним молодым петушком" (Пришв.)

(Я вспомнил две вещи: что спугивал черныша и что там жила матка с петушком)

Comment: "Подходя к дому, я вспомнил, что неподалеку в еловом перелеске с можжевельником не раз спугивал старого петуха-черныша и еще там жила матка с одним молодым петушком" (Пришв.).Интересный пример. А как в думаете наречие "еще" не помешает нам считать эти придаточные однородными?

Comment: @Vera - да, хочется поставить запятую из-за "еще", для передачи эффекта "а вот еще прямо сейчас вспомнил, что там жила..".

Comment: Да, вот на этом форуме обсуждалась эта запятая http://rusforus.ru/viewtopic.php?t=4811. Интересно, были ли варианты в авторском тексте.

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное за ответ, я отчасти запуталась.

Comment: @Маргарита - пожалуйста!